# get the value form mySQL to swift by PHP

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

i have the php file that return json_encode value and when i go to the http address they give me the value but 
i cant get the value form the server side to my apps i have try many time but its not get it

```
func loadData() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/getExpo.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    // modify the request as necessary, if necessary

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            // Display an alert message

            print(error)

            return
        }

        do {

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                if (json != nil) {

                    //let userId = parseJSON["userId"] as? String

                    // Display an alert message
                    let userMessage = json!["id"] as? String

                    print(userMessage)

                } else {

                    // Display an alert message
                    let userMessage = "Could not fetch Value"
                    print(userMessage)

                }



        } catch  {

            print(error)

        }

    }).resume()


}
```

any one can help , thank you !!

Comment: give your URl and post or get data i will check.

Comment: http://www.q8-9ndo5aan.com/kuwaitExpoApps/script/getExpo.php

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON response is an *array* of dictionaries:

> [{"id":"115","expoName":"aziz","expoDetails":"aziz","expoPhone":"aziz","expoLocation":"aziz"}]

But you're trying to cast it as a Dictionary:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

The solution of course is to cast it as an array:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

Better use Swift types if you can:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Then for example you can use a loop:

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for item in json {
        let userMessage = item["id"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: please if you can and now how to return the value to the collection view